# How to check postman response array value when attribute name more than one word

Tags: javascript, postman

I have the following response to my postman request. I want to check the "Duplicate Subscription" array first item value contains the expected text.

Can you help me with the text, please?

My Response:

```json
{
  "type": "https://httpstatuses.com/409",
    "title": "Conflict",
      "status": 409,
        "detail": "A resource with the specified parameters already exist",
          "correlationId": "f976f20f-c9b1-4822-aa15-2b5e5de3555a",
            "errors": {
    "Duplicated Subscription": [
      "Active subscriptions has reached the limit of 6 for CarrierId=AB, CustomerId=xyz. Cancel existing subscription before subscribing."
    ]
  }
}
```

This is my test which failed line number 7 :

```js
pm.test("Validate conflict Subscription stauts code", function () {
  pm.response.to.have.status(409);
  var jsonData = pm.response.json();
  pm.expect(jsonData).to.have.property("title");
  pm.expect(jsonData).to.have.property("detail");
  pm.expect(jsonData.errors).to.have.property("Duplicated Subscription");
  pm.expect(jsonData.errors).to.have.property("Duplicated Subscription")[0].to.contains("Active subscriptions has reached the limit of 6 for CarrierId=AB, CustomerId=xyz. Cancel existing subscription before subscribing.");
});
```

Comment: You are testing for a match - not the presence of a property.

Comment: @prasad_ I am testing the "Duplicate Subscription" field containing the expected text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this test unit:

> I don't know what kind of unit test you are using so please read the comment and translate it into syntax your unit test supports

```js
pm.test("Validate conflict Subscription stauts code", function(){
  pm.response.to.have.status(409);
  var jsonData = pm.response.json();
  pm.expect(jsonData).to.have.property("title");
  pm.expect(jsonData).to.have.property("detail");
  
  //pm.expect(jsonData.errors).to.have.property("Duplicated Subscription");
  //pm.expect(jsonData.errors).to.have.property("Duplicated Subscription")[0].to.contains("Active subscriptions has reached the limit of 6 for CarrierId=AB, CustomerId=xyz. Cancel existing subscription before subscribing.");

  // i don't know what unit test runner you use so i will use the unit test syntax i am familiar with and explain to you
  pm.expect(jsonData.errors["Duplicated Subscription"]).not.toBeUndefined() // check if this exists . if yes it will !== undefined
  pm.expect(jsonData.errors["Duplicated Subscription"][0]).toEqual("Active subscriptions has reached the limit of 6 for CarrierId=AB, CustomerId=xyz. Cancel existing subscription before subscribing."); // check this is equal ===
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer to this.

```
pm.expect(jsonData.errors).to.have.property("Duplicated Subscription").contains("Active subscriptions has reached the limit of 5 for CarrierId=AB, CustomerId=xyz. Cancel existing subscription before subscribing.");
```